# Django how to render ModelForm field as Multiple choice

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form like this:

```
from django.forms import widgets

class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields = ( 'name', 'location', 'options')
```

Where 'options' is a list of tuples and is automatically rendered in template as drop down menu. However I want users to be able to choose multiple options in the search form.

I know I need to add a widget to the form class as I looked at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) and it seems to me that it needs to be something like this to the class:

```
widgets = {
    'options':  ModelChoiceField(**kwargs)
}
```

However I get this error

```
name 'MultipleChoiceField' is not defined
```

So Finally could not figure out  how exactly to implement that. So appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you looking for `ModelChoiceField` or `MultipleChoiceField`? Have you imported it correctly?

Comment: Something like `from django import forms` and then call it with `forms.MultipleChoiceField`

Comment: @bnjmn of course I have imported forms in form.py. Not sure which widget should I import. I just need the output to be a multiple choice checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

`ModelChoiceField` is not a widget, it's a [form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField), but to use [multiple version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) of it, you need to override field:

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdvancedSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['options'].empty_label = None

    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields = ( 'name', 'location', 'options')
```

then to override the widget to checkboxes, use [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#checkboxselectmultiple)

```
widgets = {
    'options':  forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
}
```

Comment: could you please complete the code. I get name 'arguments' is not defined

Comment: these are arguments that you put on your own, depending on what you need, please check the docs on `ModelMultipleChoiceField` for details.

Comment: I looked at the docs and tried 'coreces' and 'empty_value' instead of '[arguments]' but both give errors. I need a working example.

Comment: @supermario are the `options` field values coming from a particular model? or are they hardcoded values?

Comment: all the fields come from the model from which the form is constructed.

Comment: @supermario ok, then just delete the line, maybe django will pick up the field itself, just use the widget part.

Comment: Yep, it works without that argument line. However the problem is that now I have a '---------' option along with the multiple choices. How to get rid of that?

Comment: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'options'